# Making linestrings with adjacent lines in Postgis

Tags: postgis, polygon, linestring

I have a Linestrings layer with all the horizontal signage (lines in the floor) in my town.

[image]

I need to calculate the area of the closed linestrings. The thing here is that every side of each closed square is a different linestring. I mean, in the image's sidewalk every rectangle/square is composed of 4 linetrings, instead of being a single linestring the whole rectangle, it is composed of 4 linestrings.

Due to this, when I convert the layer to polygon using ST_MakePolygon I am getting 0 when calculting the st_area of the sidewalk and other elements..

I guess I need to create first a single linestring for every square(rectangle but I don't know how to do it...

EDIT:
I am currently using this query to get the area of closed linestrings with very bad result:

```
SELECT sub.id, st_area(st_makepolygon(ST_ForceClosed(sub.the_geom))) as area
    FROM 
    sh_lineas sub
     where ST_NPoints(sub.the_geom)>3
```

My approach would be to create a subquery first and do ST_MakeLine with all the lines that are less than 1 cm from one to the other. Is it right?

Comment: Please post the query you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure but as far as I know there is no simple one-liner for this. You have to write some procedure to collect all intersecting lines with recurrence, join them, create polygons and then cut a holes in them (e.g. sign of triangle with a hole inside)

Comment: @JohnBarça edited with my tests

Comment: I think you need to use ST_LineMerge or ST_Union on sub.the_geom before passing that the ST_MakePolygon. ST_MakePolygon expects a linestring, which would represent the polygon.  So ST_MakePolygon(ST_LineMerge(sub.the_geom)) essentially, possibly with ST_ForceClosed.

Comment: @JohnBarça I think there is no way to do this in one select cause you have to collect lines to create a polygon... sth like group by geometry but if you know such resolution I'll be happy to see it...

Comment: @Jendrusk. Yes, you probably need a subquery to do the initial line merge. It was a general approach rather than a complete solution

Comment: @JohnBarça I think not even subquery - as I see few loops and some postprocessing, but I'm not as high level in SQL as You. I've started to write some procedure, maybe finish it tomorrow if there'll be time enough

Comment: @Jendrusk. Sorry, I was very tied up yesterday. You can do this using ST_Dump in conjuction with ST_Linemerge and ST_Union (which is effectively a spatial group by).

Comment: I have posted a solution that I have tested on some crazy UK coastline data I had lying around. Where is your vector data from, btw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in two steps using by first dumping the merged lines using [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html), formed by unioning your linestrings together (**ST_Union** effectively works as a spatial group by) and then use [ST_MakePolygon](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html), using [ST_IsClosed](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsClosed.html) to convert only those dumped geometries that are closed linestrings.

```
WITH lines(geom) AS 
  (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Linemerge(ST_Union(geom)))).geom 
     FROM some_table)
 SELECT 
    row_number() over() as id, 
    ST_MakePolygon(geom) 
 FROM lines 
 WHERE ST_Isclosed(geom);
```

You could also use things like **ST_ForceClosed**,  as you had in your original version, **ST_SnapToGrid** to further refine things, if you think there might be tiny gaps between what should be intersecting lines. If you are certain that all the lines with make up a polygon, you can actually do this as a single select, dropping the **ST_Dump** (but this is probably an unsafe approach).

The row_number() over() is just to create a unique id for each polygon, which you may not need, and could also get from the path that is returned along with each geom by ST_Dump.

With the test data in @Jendrusk's post the above produces 8 polygons, the first few of which look like:

> 1 | POLYGON((-1.14366998577525 0.177809388335704,-1.13798008534851 0.783783783783784,-1.0697012802276 0.783783783783784,-1.06543385490754 0.180654338549075,-1.14366998577525 0.177809388335704))
>
> 2 | POLYGON((-0.967972083926032 0.614153627311522,-0.534828413940256 0.614864864864865,-0.736108641536273 0.210881934566145,-0.967972083926032 0.614153627311522))
>
> 3 | POLYGON((-0.965838371266003 0.685988620199146,-0.962993421052632 0.791251778093883,-0.860575213371266 0.791251778093883,-0.860575213371266 0.683143669985775,-0.965838371266003 0.685988620199146))
>
> 4 | POLYGON((-0.896137091038407 0.577169274537696,-0.600973506401138 0.575035561877667,-0.731129978662874 0.292674253200569,-0.896137091038407 0.577169274537696))

Comment: niccce... as I said - You're The Boss :)

Comment: Of course there's cutting holes left, but this one select makes 3/4 of my procedure. I will never thinked out that you need to combine it into one big geometry to later break inot ready to use lines

Comment: @Jendrusk. Great, I do loads of work in plpgsql and love it, but sometimes there is a less obvious way to do in straight SQL.

Comment: Thanks! @JohnBarça your solution plus st_snaptogrid made it!!

Comment: @Egidi, you are welcome. Out of interest, where did you put the ST_SnapToGrid, inside the ST_Union function?

Comment: @JohnBarça Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the same problem some time ago and it could be useful for me to I decided to write [some procedure](https://github.com/jendrusk/PGSQL_Procedures/tree/master/CR_PolygonsFromLines).

Feel free to use it and/or contribute.

I'm sure there is another, maybe simpler way to do this but this is but this is also working.

Comment: Thanks for the test data. That's a cool procedure, but I'm pretty sure you can do it as a two-step query.